# How should I patch a large hole in brick?

Tags: electrical, brick

I have an old vent, about 6-8 inches in diameter, in my ranch style brick home that used to be for my stove.  We have done away with the stove and no longer need the vent.  The hole and vent is outside and leading into our unfinished basement so it would be easy to run an electrical outlet (GFI) where the hole is to where we are going to put a fountain with some landscape design.

Can I place the electrical outlet in the hole and cement around the outlet with the electrical wire into the basement?  Do I put CCA treated wood or an aluminum piece of metal inside behind the cemented hole to support the concrete inside the house?

Comment: I'm not getting a clear picture of the situation.A small hole/tunnel connects your basement to the outside garden? Now you want an electric outlet in your garden by connecting through the hole to a wire/outlet in the basement? And you are wondering how to fill up the hole with cement once you've pulled the wiring through?

Comment: Firstly, I would not anything until you know the difference between cement and concrete.

Answer (score 1):

This is the procedure:

(1) Have a REAL bricklaying-mason repair hole. Holes in brick are repaired with brick. Do not hire an idiot. It is harder to repair a brick wall than to build a brick wall.

(2) Drill 3/4" hole through wall.

(3) Put electrical conduit through wall.

(4) Seal conduit with approved material to make completely air and water tight.

(5) Mount all-weather electrical outlet to outside of wall attached to conduit..

Answer (score 0):

That is a large hole, I would probably try to find or fabricate something like this:

[image]

You could pack insulation between the inside and outside plates to stop drafts. Surface mount an exterior electrical box to the outside plate for your GFI receptacle. drill holes in the plates to pass conduit/wire through.